# Captcha for java 1.7

Tags: java, captcha

I am using `PassImageServlet.java` and `Encrypter.java` for captcha and security purpose. while compiling with java 1.7 it is showing,

> package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist import
>   com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;

Comment: update the code to import the correct classes or search for alternative captcha libraries. In General it is not a good idea to use internal classes from JDK/JRE directly.

Answer (score 1):

As you are importing libraries from the `sun.com.*` package which is usually discourages by oracle.These are in `rt.jar`, which is being used as run-time facilities by the JVM, so you should avoid having dependency on that package try using some other alternate libraries. You can try [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) as an alternate